# 64-bit Managed DirectX

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, directx

I am writing a 64 bit application.  It must run as a 64 bit application on Windows 7, which is to say that 32-bit compatibility mode is not permitted.  I want to use managed DirectX to accomplish some multimedia playback.  Where/how can I get managed 64-bit DLLs for DirectX?

Comment: Managed DirectX went the way of the Dodo, it likely won't be the best choice of framework for video playback.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Managed DirectX. The program got replaced by [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) which is likely not what you're looking for. Perhaps you should look into [DirectShow](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) or [MediaFoundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Foundation) ([.NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/)) as DirectX isn't the recommended way to perform media playback. If you're using DirectX for other reasons there are other implementations of DirectX via interop (see other answers).

Comment: Is there any official documentation from Microsoft that states that Managed DirectX was given the axe?

Comment: I don't have the links ATM but I know Microsoft employees have said so on blogs.

Answer (score 3):

Managed DirectX is deprecated. However you might want to have a look at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) (they have  64 bit support) or [sharpdx](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/).

Comment: Is there any official documentation from Microsoft that states that Managed DirectX was given the axe?

Comment: @GWLlosa I didn't find any, but it has been ages since the last release and it has pretty much been replaced by XNA. I wouldn't expect an update at this point anymore.